# Getting aggregate count for nested fields in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection mimicking this java class. A student can be taught a number of subjects across campus.

```
 class Students {
     String studentName;
     Map<String,List<String>> subjectsByCampus;
}
```

So a structure will look like this

```
{
 _id: ObjectId("someId"),
 studentName:'student1',
subjectByCampusName:{
 campus1:['subject1','subject2'],
 campus2: ['subject3']
},
_class: 'fqnOfTheEntity'
}
```

I want to find the count of subjects offered by each campus or be able to query the count of subjects offered by a specific campus. Is there a way to get it through query?

Comment: For a given student or across the entire collection?

Comment: I have both requirement.. but as of now , need for a student

Comment: I don't know if your schema is going to easily support either. For a given student - you can use the `$size` operator, but you'll need to either enumerate each `campus#` field manually or jump through some hoops with `$objectToArray`. And if you're trying to figure out the data for the entire collection, the database is going to have to process every single `students` document which will not scale well at all.

Comment: taking my code snippet, I want the output to be something like campus1:2, campus2:1. I am trying to write a query but not finding a way

Comment: based on @user20042973 answer you maybe looking for this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/adjX0QNkEK6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioned in the comments, but the schema here does not appear to be particularly well-suited toward gathering the data requested in the question. For an individual student, this is doable via `$size` and processing the object (as an array) via `$map`. For example, if we want your desired out put of `campus1:2, campus2:1` for the sample document provided, a pipeline to produce that in a `countsByCampus` field might look as follows:

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "countsByCampus": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$subjectByCampusName"
            },
            "in": {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                "$$this",
                {
                  v: {
                    $size: "$$this.v"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nhpt2aZaV6F) with an output document of:

```
  {
    "_class": "fqnOfTheEntity",
    "_id": "someId",
    "countsByCampus": {
      "campus1": 2,
      "campus2": 1
    },
    "studentName": "student1",
    "subjectByCampusName": {
      "campus1": [
        "subject1",
        "subject2"
      ],
      "campus2": [
        "subject3"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Doing that across the *entire* collection would involve `$group`ing the results together. This can be done but would be an extremely resource-intensive and likely slow operation.

Comment: this looks too complex to be honest.. but thanks for providing the details